# How to get toast consistently 30dpi from bottom?

Tags: java, android, toast

I am using a simple toast in Android and I want it to be pretty consistently placed 30dpi from the bottom of the screen for all phones so that it doesn't cover up a menu bar I have on the bottom.

I can get it to work on one phone by doing:

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your string here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
toast.setGravity(Gravity.Center, 0, 300);
toast.show();
```

But then on different sized screens it doesn't work.  Is there a different gravity I can use to make this work?

Comment: Have you ever had luck with TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30,
    myAppResources.getDisplayMetrics())?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you're close, but you should set the Gravity to `BOTTOM|CENTER_HORIZONTAL`, and then offset it by 30dp:

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();
int offset = Math.round(30 * c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, "My Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, offset);
toast.show();
```